# For Distributed Tensorflow, does each server/task separately read in input data?

Tags: tensorflow

Or is it handled by the single chief worker server/task?

We're building a between-replication and asynchronous [Distributed Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) model. But in all of the examples I've found, it seems like every device shares the exact same code (except for the if-fork that happens depending on if it's a parameter server device or a worker device). And on the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed), they don't show the input_fn() that is passed into the model.

So I was wondering if all the copies of the code that the servers/tasks share all have an input_fn() or if the chief one handles the data and sends the data to the others? Or is there something I'm missing? =(

Thanks in advance for any help. =)